# "Guilt about" vs. "Guilt over"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> - He felt a pang of **guilt** **over** lying to her girlfriend.
> - He felt a pang of **guilt about** lying to her girlfriend.

I saw many texts which contained "guilt over", but when I looked the word "guilt" up, i saw that it comes just with the preposition "about".

What is your explanation on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The online Oxford Collocation Dictionary suggests that about, at and over  are the  prepositions used with ***[guilt](http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search?word=guilt)***:

> - (PREP.) ~ ***about/at/over*** He had no feelings of guilt over what he had done.

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=guilt%20about%2Cguilty%20over%2C%20guilt%20at&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cguilt%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cguilty%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cguilt%20at%3B%2Cc0) shows that there are usage instances of *guilt over* even though they are much less common than *guilt about or guilt at*.

It appears to be just a less common variant.